# Where does 113 hail from in 13/113, Ontario's GST/HST rebate rate for employees' auto expenses?

Tags: ontario

[*Tax Planning for You and Your Family 2019*](https://home.kpmg/ca/en/home/insights/2018/11/tax-planning-for-you-and-your-family-2019.html) by KPMG. p 198.

> #### Example
>
> Michelle buys a new car in Ontario in July 2013 for $35,000 plus
>   13% HST. She is required to drive 10,000 km for employment-related
>   purposes during the year. She also drives 10,000 km on personal trips.
>
> Since half of her driving is employment-related, Michelle can claim
>   half of the capital cost allowance normally allowed for a car. Although
>   she spent $35,000, the cost is capped at $30,000, plus $3,900 HST (total
>   of $33,900), for tax purposes. The maximum capital cost allowance
>   for the year of acquisition is 15%. Fifteen percent of $33,900 is
>   $5,085. Michelle can therefore claim half of this amount, $2,543, as a
>   deduction against her employment income for 2013.
>
> Further, because she uses her car partly for business, Michelle can
>   claim an HST rebate for 2013 from the CRA equal to **13/113** of her
>   capital cost allowance claim—see 12.3.2.

p 201

> Finally, note also that **the 13/113 rebate rate is only used in provinces
>   that impose HST at the 13% rate (i.e., Ontario, New Brunswick and
>   Newfoundland and Labrador)**. Had Michelle’s expenses been incurred in
>   a province with 5% GST only or in Nova Scotia (15% HST) or British
>   Columbia (12% HST until April 1, 2013), the rebate she generally would
>   be entitled to claim for 2013 would be calculated accordingly (i.e., at 5/105,
>   15/115 or 6.75/106.75 respectively of the GST/HST-included price). (GST
>   or HST rebates are also available to members of partnerships—see 11.3.7.)
>   On April 1, 2013, B.C. returned to a GST and provincial sales tax system
>   and Prince Edward Island adopted a 14% HST (see 11.2.5).

I'm unproficient at math. I know 113 = 100 + 13, but I don't know if this relevants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common phenomenon when tax rates are converted between a percentage of net and a percentage of gross. The 13% (13/100) tax rate is based on the net (pre-tax) price. To calculate the tax from the gross (post-tax) price, the pertinent rate is 13/113. Example: Net $100, tax $13, gross $113.